# Limit the queried list content using EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Using EF I would like to query data from the DB with 2 constraints, one is ID and the second one is the status of one of the items in an array.

DATA STRUCTURE:

```
TableA:
{
    ID,
    TableB:
    {
         TableC:
         [
         {
              Status, 
              Name, 
              ...
         },
         ]
    }
}
```

Currently, I have the following code:

```
int[] IDS = new int[3] {1, 3, 6};

TableA[] result = await context.TableA
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.TableB)
                           .ThenInclude(y => y.TableC)
                    .Where(x => IDS.Contains(x.TableB.ID) &&
                           x.TableB.TableC.Where(y => y.Status == "Awesome").Count() > 0)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToArrayAsync();
```

The End goal is to get items that have their id containing in the array and to only get elements from TableC which have the status of **Awesome**. Currently, I get all values in the array as the result, and I know this can be done, as I have already done this in an SQL Query, but somehow I can't reproduce it using  EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
       int[] IDS = new int[3] { 1, 3, 6 };
       TableA[] result = await _context.TableA
                            .Include(x => x.TableB)
                                   .ThenInclude(y => y.TableC)
                            .Where(x => IDS.Contains(x.TableB.ID))
                            .Select(x => new TableA
                            {
                                ID = x.ID,
                                TableB = new TableB()
                                {
                                    ID = x.TableB.ID,
                                    TableC = x.TableB.TableC.Where(c => c.Status == "Awesome").ToList()
                                }
                            }).AsNoTracking()
                            .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: So not letting the system do its thing and manually selecting the values I want actually works!? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] IDS = new int[3] {1, 3, 6};

TableA[] result = await context.TableA
                    .Include(x => x.TableB)
                           .ThenInclude(y => y.TableC)
                    .Where(x => IDS.Contains(x.TableB.ID) &&
                           x.TableB.TableC.Any(c => c.Status== "Awesome")
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Unfortunately.Any() does not affect, thank you for trying

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were super close. I think this will get it.

```cs
TableA[] result = await context.TableA
    .ThenInclude(x => x.TableB)
        .ThenInclude(y => y.TableC)
    .Where(x => IDS.Contains(x.TableB.ID) &&
        x.TableB.TableC.Status.Any(y => y == "Awesome")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Let me know if that that gets what you need. If you need that count value > 0 as well, add it as another && in the where clause.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `TableC` is actually a collection instead of a single instance.  Otherwise they wouldn't be able to do `Where` on it.

Comment: @juharr thanks for spotting that. Added the Any clause that should catch that condition correctly.

Comment: That should get the same results.  They want to actually filter out the values in TableCs.

Comment: I @juharr I see where I went wrong after reading the question again. He needs a join, I'll have to edit in a bit when I have a moment.

Comment: HI! Yes, the TableC is an array, and my end goal is to get all distinct names from the values of TableC, but only those with status "Awesome" qualify. I could do this after I retrieve the data, but the thing is I know this can be done more efficiently before I get the data from the DB.

Comment: P.S. The .Count() is there only to provide a bool for the previous .Where()